# order of validation summary control messages

Tags: validation

Can any one of you help me in controlling

1. The order in which the error messages appear in validation summary control.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is source code of sorting ValidationSummaryItem, hope it will help you

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Compare ValidationSummaryItems for display in the ValidationSummary
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">The first reference used for comparison.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The second reference used for comparison.</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the comparison check between the two references.</returns>
        internal static int CompareValidationSummaryItems(ValidationSummaryItem x, ValidationSummaryItem y)
        {
            int returnVal;
            if (!ReferencesAreValid(x, y, out returnVal))
            {
                // Do a null comparison check if one (or both) are null
                return returnVal;
            }

            // Compare ErrorSource
            if (TryCompareReferences(x.ItemType, y.ItemType, out returnVal))
            {
                return returnVal;
            }

            // Compare Control
            Control controlX = x.Sources.Count > 0 ? x.Sources[0].Control : null;
            Control controlY = y.Sources.Count > 0 ? y.Sources[0].Control : null;

            if (controlX != controlY)
            {
                if (!ReferencesAreValid(controlX, controlY, out returnVal))
                {
                    // Do a null comparison check if one is null
                    return returnVal;
                }

                // Both are controls
                if (controlX.TabIndex != controlY.TabIndex)
                {
                    // Sort by TabIndex
                    return controlX.TabIndex.CompareTo(controlY.TabIndex);
                }

                // Both share the same parent, sort by index
                returnVal = SortByVisualTreeOrdering(controlX, controlY);
                if (returnVal != 0)
                {
                    return returnVal;
                }

                // TabIndexes and ordering are the same, move to next check
                if (TryCompareReferences(controlX.Name, controlY.Name, out returnVal))
                {
                    return returnVal;
                }
            }

            // If we reached this point, we could not compare by Control, TabIndex, nor Name.  
            // Compare by MessageHeader
            if (TryCompareReferences(x.MessageHeader, y.MessageHeader, out returnVal))
            {
                return returnVal;
            }

            // Compare by ErrorMessage
            TryCompareReferences(x.Message, y.Message, out returnVal);
            return returnVal;
        }
```